# Inheriting doc strings in Python + preview in IDE

Tags: python, spyder

I am currently spending some time writing a wrapper for matplotlib for easier creation of plots for publications etc.

Currently I am using Spyder as IDE and I really like the Object Inspector feature which provides live documentation for the objects you are working with.

Anyways, part of my API only forwards calls to a matplotlib function and it would therefore be very handy to inherit the documentation from those.

Writing `myfunction.__doc__ = matplotlibfunction.__doc__` seems to work if I print `__doc__` to the console, but the Object Inspector in Spyder does not show the documentation, do anyone have a good suggestion as to why, and what I could do to get the intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Greg, are you trying to view `myfuncion` docstring from the Editor? The thing is Spyder relies on the [rope](http://rope.sourceforge.net/) library to do docstring inspection on the Editor, which unfortunately has several shortcomings we'll try to fix on the 2.2 version.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do. Thinking of it, maybe I should have posted this in the spyder group instead, but thanks for the answer! I will be looking forward to the 2.2 release then :)